# Reduce not being saved in variable value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use reduce to get the sum of these values:

```
  let test = [{foo: 234}, {foo: 122}];

   let result = test.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return acc + curr['foo'];
   },0);
```

I see the result in console, 356, but the variable result is `null` whenever I check the value of `result`.  Am I using reduce incorrectly?

Comment: You're doing it right. When I log `result`, it shows 356.

Comment: No, but you are checking the value of `result` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any problem in your code... ;)

```js
let test = [{foo: 234}, {foo: 122}];

let result = test.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   return acc + curr['foo'];
},0); 

document.body.innerHTML = `<strong>result = ${result}</strong>`;
```

Comment: thanks!  Not sure what happened.  I refreshed and still same `null` after pasting the code into Chrome.  I closed out chrome entirely, tried again and bingo.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯